# Play Framework: `#` appears in the generated SQL file

Tags: sql, playframework-2.0

I am following [this James Ward Playframework tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_YYgl65FLs) and around 27:00 there is a generated SQL file that has `#` signs throughout. What do these mean? Is there a term for this? (I added the file below)

When I deleted them to conform to SQL syntax, I got a SQLException where my table could not be found. I am keeping the `#` symbols, but I do not understand why they are there. Can anyone explain?

Here is the file, for reference:

```
#--- Created by Ebean DDL
# To stop Ebean DDL generation, remove this comment and start using Evolutions

# --- !Ups

create table bar (
  id                        varchar(255) not null,
  name                      varchar(255),
  constraint pk_bar primary key (id))
;

create sequence bar_seq;




# --- !Downs

SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE;

drop table if exists bar;

SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY TRUE;

drop sequence if exists bar_seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

This file is part of [Evolutions plugin](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Evolutions). Basically, it allows updating database schema when Play server starts up. I suspect, Ebean has integration with evolutions and it creates these files. '#' symbol is a part of evolutions plugin syntax.